# Java: Importing resources, the use of "*"?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, awt

I am currently working on a tutorial that uses the following imports:

```
//importing Resources
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.*;
```

My question is: does java.awt.* import everything from awt? And if so why is this necessary?

```
 import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is: does java.awt.* import everything from awt?

It imports all the classes in `java.awt`, but that's all.

> And if so why is this necessary?
>
> ```
> import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
> ```

Because that's not in `java.awt` - it's in `java.awt.event`. Packages in Java aren't *really* hierarchical, even though they look that way. As far as the Java language is concerned, `java.awt` and `java.awt.event` are entirely separate packages.